# Python console_script installed in virtual environment - executable location not automatically updated

Tags: python, pip, executable

I have a Python package configured to build as a console_script which is working fine. I have it installed globally which is linked to my Mac's homebrew Python 3.9 installation.

The command is called `rfi`, excerpt from setup.py:

```py
setup(
    # include data files
    data_files=data_files,
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['rfi=my_package.app:main']
    },
    name='package_name',
    version="1.0",
    install_requires=install_requires
)
```

When I run `which rfi`, this is the console output:

```bash
/opt/homebrew/bin/rfi
```

For testing purposes, I wanted to install a fresh copy using a new virtual environment. I created and activated the environment, then ran `pip install` to install the package.

I can see in the venv bin that the `rfi` executable is present and content is correct. However, when I run `which rfi`, it still points at `/opt/homebrew/bin/rfi`.

Is there a way to configure setup.py or something else so that when I run `pip install` from within a venv, the executable path is automatically updated so that I can simply run `rfi` command, and it will use the venv version? Currently to use the venv version, I have to run `/path/to/venv/bin/rfi`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this for now by adding the following to the end of my setup.py script:

```py
os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.join(os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'], 'bin') + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
```

This adds the new virtual environment's bin to the beginning of PATH, so it is used instead of the global python bin for locating executables.

Then, in my shell after running `pip install` I have to run the following:

```bash
hash -r
```

This clears the shell's cache of executables and reloads it using latest `PATH`. Without this, even though `PATH` is correct, the global python bin is still used. I'm using zsh for reference.